# How can babel transform ES7 to ES6 only?

Tags: babeljs, jsdoc, ecmascript-2016

JSDos work with ES6 very well, but my project use some ES7 syntax, and JSDoc does not support ES7. I've tried to transform my code to ES5 before pipe to JSDoc, but JSDoc won't work, so I think I should transform every file into ES6 before pipe to JSDocs, the transform must ignore "import" and "require" syntax, can babel do this, or is there any transform tool can do this?

Comment: Just enable the transformations for the ES7 features only?

Comment: Just enable the transformations for ES7 to ES6 and ignore "import" and "require" syntax.

Comment: ES7 didn't really introduce any new syntax. Anyway, yes, Babel will only transform what you tell it to transform. Have a look at the documentation: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/ .